# WiQuery version for Wicket 1.5.10

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5, wiquery

Which WiQuery version is proper for Wicket 1.5.10? Is it WiQuery 1.5.8 (the last from 1.5.x branch) or can be used the new version 6.6.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [WiQuery project page](https://code.google.com/p/wiquery/) says, version 6.x has been compiled against Wicket 6.x, so you won't be able to use it with Wicket 1.5.

The latest WiQuery version compiled against 1.5 and available in Maven central is 1.5.8.